# Same type textfield in UItableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a tableview with custom uitableview cell contains label and textfield. The number of rows will depends on the value which are coming from API. All the textfiled will be in number type. So my question is how can I do call textfield did enter and textfield should return and how it will work?

Textfield Begin Editing

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField//Should begin editing
{
_tblVw_TargetSetting.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 244, 0);

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tblVw_TargetSetting indexPathForCell:cell];

for (NSInteger i = indexPath.row; i<[arrTargetSettingList count];) 
{
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)i);

if(i==[arrTargetSettingList count]-1)
{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

[mCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULLWIDTH, 50)];

numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)], [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(DoneWithNumberPad)],
                                       nil];

[numberToolbar sizeToFit];

valNumberPad = i;

mCell.txtFld_TargetSetting.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;

}

else{

if(i==0){

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULLWIDTH, 50)];

numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(nextWithNumberPad)],
                                           nil];

[numberToolbar sizeToFit];

valNumberPad = i;

mCell.txtFld_TargetSetting.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;

}

else{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row-1 
inSection:indexPath.section];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

[mCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];

UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, FULLWIDTH, 50)];
    numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(nextWithNumberPad)], nil];[numberToolbar sizeToFit];

valNumberPad = i;

mCell.txtFld_TargetSetting.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;

}

}

break;
}

return YES;

}
```

textfield Should Return

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField//should return
{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tblVw_TargetSetting indexPathForCell:cell];
for (NSInteger i = indexPath.row; i<[arrTargetSettingList count];) {

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mAddressDetailsCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[mAddressDetailsCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

[cell.txtFld_TargetSetting becomeFirstResponder];

break;

}

return YES;

}
> Toolbar Button Tap Methods

-(void)cancelNumberPad{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:valNumberPad inSection:0];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tblVw_TargetSetting indexPathForCell:cell];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mAddressDetailsCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[mAddressDetailsCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

CGRect frame = self.tblVw_TargetSetting.frame;

self.tblVw_TargetSetting.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 223.0f, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

_tblVw_TargetSetting.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
 [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void)nextWithNumberPad{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:valNumberPad inSection:0];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tblVw_TargetSetting indexPathForCell:cell];        

for (NSInteger i = valNumberPad; i<[arrTargetSettingList count];) {

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mAddressDetailsCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[mAddressDetailsCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];            

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i+1 inSection:indexPath.section];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

[cell.txtFld_TargetSetting becomeFirstResponder];

break;

}

}

-(void)DoneWithNumberPad{

NSIndexPath *sibling = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:valNumberPad inSection:0];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *cell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:sibling];

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_tblVw_TargetSetting indexPathForCell:cell];

TargetSettingTableViewCell *mAddressDetailsCell = [_tblVw_TargetSetting cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

[mAddressDetailsCell.txtFld_TargetSetting resignFirstResponder];        

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

CGRect frame = self.tblVw_TargetSetting.frame;

self.tblVw_TargetSetting.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 223.0f,frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

_tblVw_TargetSetting.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: call the textfield delegate method.

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are trying to achieve or what your problem is. Please rethink your question and edit it or ask again. If you want the replies in a specific language tag that language only, don't tag both Objective-C and Swift.

Comment: Just set custom tableview cell class as the delegate to the textfield and compare sender to your textfield objects(or you can use tags) to identify the textfield.

Comment: Emilio- I want to ask i have textfield in custom cell and also set the tag in cellforrowatindexpath by using indexpath.row. The number of rows will depends on the value which are come from webservice. So the number of rows dynamic not fixed. So how can I call didbeginedit and shouldenter two delegates of textfield and how it will work? I am doing this in objective C

Comment: those delegate methods will be called automatically.

Comment: both are delegate method so that event will be occur then it will be called automatically .

Comment: what you want to do additionally .?

Comment: Delegates are called as all the textfield is number type so when I click next(using toolbar for that) is not called didbeginediting

Comment: Please edit your question properly and explain clearly.

Comment: As per your comment, your question is completely different .

Comment: Why should anyone take any time to help you if you can't even take the time to format your question so it is readable? If you want people to put effort into helping you, start by putting effort into your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late as i am new in stackoverflow so dont be mad.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, First you need to create Custom UITableViewCell like this way.

```
class PersonalInfoCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var lblTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Then Implement `UITableView` delegate method like this way

```
class PersonalInfoVC : UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate
{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PersonalInfoCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PersonalInfoCell
        cell.txtField.delegate = self
        cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell

    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

I hope above simple example you will get idea.

Comment: Thanks jignesh. I have done this already in objective c but how can I check the textfield to change frame of tableview?

Comment: i am not getting your question properly,what functionality you required?

Comment: @jigneshVadadoriya Just for sake, but you will have to identify the textfield by comparing object or tags.

Comment: BY textField.tag you can identify the value

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your custom cell class

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var txtField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var lblTitle: UILabel!

    func configure() {
        self.txtField.delegate = self
        //This can also be done through storyboard(xib)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //Do your work
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //Do your work
    }
}
```

Just call the configure method from cellForRow and the delegate methods will be called directly.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.Please try it.

Please set in cellForRowAtIndexPath method as:

```
textField.delegate = self;
textField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then in didbeginedit method write.

```
UITextField *txtfld1 = (UITextField *)[yourTableName viewWithTag:0]; 
UITextField *txtfld1 = (UITextField *)[yourTableName viewWithTag:1];
```

If You have no of text field the you can use for loop.

I hope it helps to you.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've implemented the UITextFieldDelegate for your class. First set tags for each of the textFields while creating the cells.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! YourCell
    cell.txtField.delegate = self
    cell.txtField.tag = indexPath.row
    return cell
}
```

Now whenever the textField delegate methods are called, you can perform actions based on the tag

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        // perform actions here
    }
} 

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    if textField.tag == 1 {
        //perform actions here
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps....

1. In cellForRowAtIndexPath method add following lines

   cell.txtField?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.updateUserInput), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
   cell.txtField?.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row
   if(indexPath.row == lastIndex) {
      cell.txtField?.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone
   }
   else
      cell.txtField?.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext
2. Create a model class to update the user input for all textfields in different cells
3. Update text from textfield to your model class in 'updateUserInput' method
4. Your textFieldShouldReturn method should be like this

   ```
   //Mark - UITextField delegates
       func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField : UITextField) -> Bool {
           let returnTypeValue = textField.returnKeyType
           if returnTypeValue == .done || returnTypeValue == .default {
               textField.resignFirstResponder()
           }
           else if returnTypeValue == .next {
               let currentRow : Int = textField.tag
               if (currentRow + 1 < inputKeysArr.count) {
                   self.respondToField(currentRow + 1, errorField: "")
               }
               else {
                   textField.resignFirstResponder()
               }
           }
           return true
       }

       func respondToField(_ count: Int, errorField : String) {
       if count < inputKeysArr.count {
           //WE have more inputs to be made as become first responder

           let nextIndexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath.init(row: count, section: 0)
           tableView?.scrollToRow(at: nextIndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.middle, animated: true)
           scrollingCompletionClosure = {
               (weakRef: ViewController) -> Void in
           }

           let nonOptionalCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
           let cell: UITableViewCell = (tableView!.cellForRow(at: nextIndexPath)) ?? nonOptionalCell
           if (cell.isKind(of: TableCell.self)) {
               let cell : TableCell = cell as! TableCell
               cell.txtField?.becomeFirstResponder()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this will help...